# Wie schließe ich eine Frage, wenn sie auf einer anderen Seite besser aufgehoben ist?

Tags: support, feature-request

Es ist schon häufiger vorgekommen, dass Leute Fragen über Sachverhalte in Deutschland stellen, die aber auf dieser Seite über die deutsche Sprache off-topic sind. Bei den vote-to-close Optionen gibt es die Möglichkeit auszuwählen, dass die Frage auf eine andere Seite gehört, ich kann dann allerdings nur German Language Meta auswählen. Ist das gewollt, fehlt mir Reputation oder was ist der Sinn dahinter?